# sql stored procedure execute command

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've created the following stored procedure on sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_generate_report (@YEAR  INT,
                                     @MONTH INT)
AS
    DECLARE @CATEGORY VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @BEGIN_DATE DATE
    DECLARE @END_DATE DATE
BEGIN
      SELECT @BEGIN_DATE = Cast(( Cast(@YEAR AS VARCHAR) + '-' 
                         + Cast(@MONTH AS VARCHAR) + '-' + '1' ) AS DATE)

      SELECT @END_DATE = Cast(( Cast(@YEAR AS VARCHAR) + '-' + 
                                Cast(@MONTH AS VARCHAR) + '-' + '32' ) AS DATE)

      SELECT TOP 1 @CATEGORY = Name
      FROM   dbo.Profitible_categories(@BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE)

      INSERT INTO dbo.MONTHLY_SUMMARY_REPORTS
      VALUES      (@CATEGORY)
  END
```

The procedure was created successfully, but when I try to execute it with the following command:

```
EXECUTE SP_GENERATE_REPORT 2012, 7
```

I get this error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_GENERATE_REPORT, Line 8
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: No month has 32 days...

Comment: And roughly half of them don't have 31 days either. You should use date arithmetic to get the last date of a month (start date +1 month - 1 day). Besides, the YYYY-MM-DD format is locale-specific. You should use one of the DATEFROMPARTS variant to create a date from year, month and day, or the YYYYMMDD format

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - IIRC `YYYY-MM-DD` (ISO) is unambiguous for casting to `date` but not for `datetime`. Agree with rest of your comment though.

Comment: apparantly Tamil calendars CAN have 32 days in a month (it's on wikipedia so it must be true; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_calendar).  Agree with the rest of @PanagiotisKanavos's comment; calculate the last day of the month.

Comment: This is not the ISO format (126). ISO formats are either yyyymmdd (112) or the full date and time (126, 127). Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191307(v=sql.100).aspx where it is recommended to use the yyyymmdd format in T-SQL, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx where the formats are listed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "The default string literal format, which is used for down-level clients, complies with the SQL standard form which is defined as YYYY-MM-DD. This format is the same as the ISO 8601 definition for DATE." [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately YYYY-MM-DD is not always safe. `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH`, for example.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - That is for `datetime`. The new datatypes are consistent. [See Tibor's article here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2007/08/04/is-yyyy-mm-dd-always-treated-as-year-month-date.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith understood, but only `YYYYMMDD` is safe across both new and old data types.

Comment: As I said (and the documentation links show), YYYY-MM-DD is not an ISO format. The ISO formats are yyyymmdd (112), yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (126) and yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ (127)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The documentation I linked to earlier says that it is (for `Date`)

Comment: The ISO format is not relevant if SQL Server doesn't obey them 100%. You also need to consider how your format is interpreted by SQL Server, since the ISO committee is not interpreting your code, SQL Server is.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - The OP is casting to `date` so in this instance it is not locale specific is the point I'm making.

Comment: it hasn't worked even with smaller values. I tried everything that I thought of. the idea is to get the end of the month. but it hasn't worked even if I wrote 31,30,29. and about the DATEFROMPARTS functions -  I read about it, but it works only in 2012 version and the version we have at the university is not that advanced.

Comment: Understood for this instance. I'm speaking in the general case for other readers. I don't advocate `yyyy-mm-dd` even if using the new types, because it may be using date today, but they may change it tomorrow. Does someone really need to keep in the back of their mind that if they later change the data type, they also have to change the format? I'd rather consistently use the same safe format, then I don't have to worry about which data type is being chosen.

Comment: @user1472066 why do you need the "end of the month"? If you want February 2010, your function should just take `'20100201'` - and then say `WHERE data >= @start AND date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @start);`. You don't need the end of the month at all.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yep. See where you are coming from.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Also see Wikipedia article for [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the last day of the month without all that nasty string concatenation or trying to guess which month it is and pick the last day.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sp_generate_report
  @YEAR  INT,
  @MONTH INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @BEGIN_DATE DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, @MONTH-1, CONVERT(DATE,
    CONVERT(CHAR(4), YEAR) + '0101'));
  DECLARE @END_DATE DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @BEGIN_DATE));

  INSERT INTO dbo.MONTHLY_SUMMARY_REPORTS
    SELECT TOP (1) Name
      FROM   dbo.Profitible_categories(@BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE);
END
GO
```